# Have a window track a component's location on screen

Tags: java, swing

In Java Swing, I want a Window to show up right next to a component--so it will float on top of the GUI. But I need it to always stay right next to that specific component wherever it moves, whether the user moves the window, scrolls the scroll pane that the component is in, resizes, etc. Is there a straightforward way to do this?

I already know how to get it to show up in the right place to begin with. So, for example, if there was some  event that fires anytime a component has changed location on the screen, that would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found it. The java.awt.Component.addHierarchyBoundsListener fires events when scrollbars move, windows move or resize. I think that will do what I need.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [`Componet#getLocationOnScreen`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getLocationOnScreen%28%29)

You're going to have to take into account the size of the component and the possibility that the window could be opened outside of the current screen bounds, but lets start with small steps

Comment: I'll add to the question: I know how to get it to show up there to begin with. It's getting it to stay relative to that component even when that component moves on the screen that is the challenge.

Comment: The best solution I can think of, is search for a reference to the parent Window (SwingUtilities has methods to do this) and using something like a Timer monitor for changes. I'd have to do some exploration, but I don't windows fire property change events when there location is modified

Comment: Not just the window, I'd have to register resize, move, and scroll events on every container all the way up the hierarchy from the component to the window. That's really messy, that's why I asked if there was a *straightforward* way to do this.

Comment: No, not a straight forward way. You will need to monitor the component (for size/location changes), the parent of the component (for size/location changes), the content pane and the window some how...in fact, you'd probably need to monitor the entire component hierarchy all the way up to the window